# Sort (order) data frame rows by multiple columns

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, r-faq

I want to sort a data frame by multiple columns. For example, with the data frame below I would like to sort by column 'z' (descending) then by column 'b' (ascending):

```
dd <- data.frame(b = factor(c("Hi", "Med", "Hi", "Low"), 
      levels = c("Low", "Med", "Hi"), ordered = TRUE),
      x = c("A", "D", "A", "C"), y = c(8, 3, 9, 9),
      z = c(1, 1, 1, 2))
dd
    b x y z
1  Hi A 8 1
2 Med D 3 1
3  Hi A 9 1
4 Low C 9 2
```

Answer (score 1788, accepted):

You can use the [`order()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/order.html) function directly without resorting to add-on tools -- see this simpler answer which uses a trick right from the top of the `example(order)` code:

```
R> dd[with(dd, order(-z, b)), ]
    b x y z
4 Low C 9 2
2 Med D 3 1
1  Hi A 8 1
3  Hi A 9 1
```

*Edit some 2+ years later:*  It was just asked how to do this by column index. The answer is to simply pass the desired sorting column(s) to the `order()` function:

```
R> dd[order(-dd[,4], dd[,1]), ]
    b x y z
4 Low C 9 2
2 Med D 3 1
1  Hi A 8 1
3  Hi A 9 1
R>
```

rather than using the name of the column (and `with()` for easier/more direct access).

Comment: Should work the same way, but you can't use `with`. Try `M <- matrix(c(1,2,2,2,3,6,4,5), 4, 2, byrow=FALSE, dimnames=list(NULL, c("a","b")))` to create a matrix `M`, then use `M[order(M[,"a"],-M[,"b"]),]` to order it on two columns.

Comment: Easy enough: `dd[ order(-dd[,4], dd[,1]), ]`, but can't use `with` for name-based subsetting.

Comment: why is `dd[ order(-dd[,4],, ]` not valid or 'dd[ order(-dd[,4], ]' basically why is `dd[,1]` required? is `-dd[,4]` not enough if you just want to sort by 1 column?

Comment: The "invalid argument to unary operator" error occurs when you use minus with a character column.  Solve it by wrapping the column in `xtfrm`, for example `dd[ order(-xtfrm(dd[,4]), dd[,1]), ]`.

Answer (score 588):

#### Your choices

- `order` from `base`
- `arrange` from `dplyr`
- `setorder` and `setorderv` from `data.table`
- `arrange` from `plyr`
- `sort` from `taRifx`
- `orderBy` from `doBy`
- `sortData` from `Deducer`

Most of the time you should use the `dplyr` or `data.table` solutions, unless having no-dependencies is important, in which case use `base::order`.

---

I recently added sort.data.frame to a CRAN package, making it class compatible as discussed here:
[Best way to create generic/method consistency for sort.data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836963/best-way-to-create-generic-method-consistency-for-sort-data-frame)

Therefore, given the data.frame dd, you can sort as follows:

```
dd <- data.frame(b = factor(c("Hi", "Med", "Hi", "Low"), 
      levels = c("Low", "Med", "Hi"), ordered = TRUE),
      x = c("A", "D", "A", "C"), y = c(8, 3, 9, 9),
      z = c(1, 1, 1, 2))
library(taRifx)
sort(dd, f= ~ -z + b )
```

If you are one of the original authors of this function, please contact me.  Discussion as to public domaininess is here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1094290#1094290

---

You can also use the `arrange()` function from `plyr` as Hadley pointed out in the above thread:

```
library(plyr)
arrange(dd,desc(z),b)
```

---

Benchmarks: Note that I loaded each package in a new R session since there were a lot of conflicts.  In particular loading the doBy package causes `sort` to return "The following object(s) are masked from 'x (position 17)': b, x, y, z", and loading the Deducer package overwrites `sort.data.frame` from Kevin Wright or the taRifx package.

```
#Load each time
dd <- data.frame(b = factor(c("Hi", "Med", "Hi", "Low"), 
      levels = c("Low", "Med", "Hi"), ordered = TRUE),
      x = c("A", "D", "A", "C"), y = c(8, 3, 9, 9),
      z = c(1, 1, 1, 2))
library(microbenchmark)

# Reload R between benchmarks
microbenchmark(dd[with(dd, order(-z, b)), ] ,
    dd[order(-dd$z, dd$b),],
    times=1000
)
```

Median times:

`dd[with(dd, order(-z, b)), ]` **778**

`dd[order(-dd$z, dd$b),]` **788**

```
library(taRifx)
microbenchmark(sort(dd, f= ~-z+b ),times=1000)
```

Median time: **1,567**

```
library(plyr)
microbenchmark(arrange(dd,desc(z),b),times=1000)
```

Median time: **862**

```
library(doBy)
microbenchmark(orderBy(~-z+b, data=dd),times=1000)
```

Median time: **1,694**

Note that doBy takes a good bit of time to load the package.

```
library(Deducer)
microbenchmark(sortData(dd,c("z","b"),increasing= c(FALSE,TRUE)),times=1000)
```

Couldn't make Deducer load.  Needs JGR console.

```
esort <- function(x, sortvar, ...) {
attach(x)
x <- x[with(x,order(sortvar,...)),]
return(x)
detach(x)
}

microbenchmark(esort(dd, -z, b),times=1000)
```

Doesn't appear to be compatible with microbenchmark due to the attach/detach.

---

```
m <- microbenchmark(
  arrange(dd,desc(z),b),
  sort(dd, f= ~-z+b ),
  dd[with(dd, order(-z, b)), ] ,
  dd[order(-dd$z, dd$b),],
  times=1000
  )

uq <- function(x) { fivenum(x)[4]}  
lq <- function(x) { fivenum(x)[2]}

y_min <- 0 # min(by(m$time,m$expr,lq))
y_max <- max(by(m$time,m$expr,uq)) * 1.05
  
p <- ggplot(m,aes(x=expr,y=time)) + coord_cartesian(ylim = c( y_min , y_max )) 
p + stat_summary(fun.y=median,fun.ymin = lq, fun.ymax = uq, aes(fill=expr))
```

[image: microbenchmark plot]

(lines extend from lower quartile to upper quartile, dot is the median)

---

Given these results and weighing simplicity vs. speed, I'd have to give the nod to **`arrange` in the `plyr` package**.  It has a simple syntax and yet is almost as speedy as the base R commands with their convoluted machinations.  Typically brilliant Hadley Wickham work.  My only gripe with it is that it breaks the standard R nomenclature where sorting objects get called by `sort(object)`, but I understand why Hadley did it that way due to issues discussed in the question linked above.

Comment: The ggplot2 microbenchmark function above is now available as `taRifx::autoplot.microbenchmark`.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman using 'arrange', how do we sort by ascending? I never see examples sorting in ascending order. I tried 'asc' instead of 'desc' and it doesn't work. thanks

Comment: @AME look at how `b` is sorted in the sample.  The default is sort by ascending, so you just don't wrap it in `desc`.  Ascending in both: `arrange(dd,z,b)` . Descending in both: `arrange(dd,desc(z),desc(b))`.

Comment: As per `?arrange`: "# NOTE: plyr functions do NOT preserve row.names". This makes the excellent `arrange()` function suboptimal if one wants to keep `row.names`.

Comment: Some of these that use `order` might be a bit faster if you use `sort.list(x, method=“radix”)` instead.

Comment: A fast and class-agnostic version that has the speed of `data.table` but returns a copy of the data frame is provided by the `collapse` functions `roworder` and `roworderv`. This should be added to the primary options as it provides a substantially faster alternative to `dplyr::arrange` but returns a copy of the data, in contrast to `data.table::setorder` which modifies the data in place and may be undesirable. see [here](https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/articles/collapse_intro.html#2-3-reordering-rows-and-columns) for details.

Answer (score 174):

Dirk's answer is great. It also highlights a key difference in the syntax used for indexing `data.frame`s and `data.table`s:

```
## The data.frame way
dd[with(dd, order(-z, b)), ]

## The data.table way: (7 fewer characters, but that's not the important bit)
dd[order(-z, b)]
```

The difference between the two calls is small, but it can have important consequences. Especially if you write production code and/or are concerned with correctness in your research, it's best to avoid unnecessary repetition of variable names. `data.table`
 helps you do this.

Here's an example of how repetition of variable names might get you into trouble:

Let's change the context from Dirk's answer, and say this is part of a bigger project where there are a lot of object names and they are long and meaningful; instead of `dd` it's called `quarterlyreport`. It becomes :

```
quarterlyreport[with(quarterlyreport,order(-z,b)),]
```

Ok, fine. Nothing wrong with that. Next your boss asks you to include last quarter's report in the report. You go through your code, adding an object `lastquarterlyreport` in various places and somehow (how on earth?) you end up with this :

```
quarterlyreport[with(lastquarterlyreport,order(-z,b)),]
```

That isn't what you meant but you didn't spot it because you did it fast and it's nestled on a page of similar code. The code doesn't fall over (no warning and no error) because R thinks it is what you meant. You'd hope whoever reads your report spots it, but maybe they don't. If you work with programming languages a lot then this situation may be all to familiar. It was a "typo" you'll say. I'll fix the "typo" you'll say to your boss.

In [`data.table`](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) we're concerned about tiny details like this. So we've done something simple to avoid typing variable names twice. Something very simple. `i` is evaluated within the frame of `dd` already, automatically. You don't need `with()` at all.

Instead of

```
dd[with(dd, order(-z, b)), ]
```

it's just

```
dd[order(-z, b)]
```

And instead of

```
quarterlyreport[with(lastquarterlyreport,order(-z,b)),]
```

it's just

```
quarterlyreport[order(-z,b)]
```

It's a very small difference, but it might just save your neck one day. When weighing up the different answers to this question, consider counting the repetitions of variable names as one of your criteria in deciding.  Some answers have quite a few repeats, others have none.

Comment: +1 This is a great point, and gets at a detail of R's syntax that has often irritated me. I sometimes use `subset()` just to avoid having to repeatedly refer to the same object within a single call.

Comment: I guess you could add the new `setorder` function too here, as this thread is where we send all the `order` type dupes.

Answer (score 154):

There are a lot of excellent answers here, but [dplyr](http://github.com/hadley/dplyr) gives the only syntax that I can quickly and easily remember (and so now use very often):

```
library(dplyr)
# sort mtcars by mpg, ascending... use desc(mpg) for descending
arrange(mtcars, mpg)
# sort mtcars first by mpg, then by cyl, then by wt)
arrange(mtcars , mpg, cyl, wt)
```

For the OP's problem:

```
arrange(dd, desc(z),  b)

    b x y z
1 Low C 9 2
2 Med D 3 1
3  Hi A 8 1
4  Hi A 9 1
```

Comment: The accepted answer does not work when my columns are or type factor (or something like that) and I want to sort in descending fashion for this factor column followed by integer column in ascending fashion. But this works just fine! Thank you!

Comment: Why "only"? I find data.table's `dd[order(-z, b)]` pretty easy to use and remember.

Comment: Agreed, there's not much between those two methods, and `data.table` is a huge contribution to `R` in many other ways also. I suppose for me, it might be that having one less set of brackets (or one less type of brackets) in this instance reduces the cognitive load by a just barely perceivable amount.

Comment: For me it comes down to the fact that `arrange()` is completely declarative, `dd[order(-z, b)]` is not.

Answer (score 103):

The R package `data.table` provides both *fast* and *memory efficient* ordering of *data.tables* with a straightforward syntax (a part of which Matt has highlighted quite nicely [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10758086/559784)). There has been quite a lot of improvements and also a new function `setorder()` since then. From `v1.9.5+`, `setorder()` also works with *data.frames*.

First, we'll create a dataset big enough and benchmark the different methods mentioned from other answers and then list the features of *data.table*.

#### Data:

```
require(plyr)
require(doBy)
require(data.table)
require(dplyr)
require(taRifx)

set.seed(45L)
dat = data.frame(b = as.factor(sample(c("Hi", "Med", "Low"), 1e8, TRUE)),
                 x = sample(c("A", "D", "C"), 1e8, TRUE),
                 y = sample(100, 1e8, TRUE),
                 z = sample(5, 1e8, TRUE), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

#### Benchmarks:

The timings reported are from running `system.time(...)` on these functions shown below. The timings are tabulated below (in the order of slowest to fastest).

```
orderBy( ~ -z + b, data = dat)     ## doBy
plyr::arrange(dat, desc(z), b)     ## plyr
arrange(dat, desc(z), b)           ## dplyr
sort(dat, f = ~ -z + b)            ## taRifx
dat[with(dat, order(-z, b)), ]     ## base R

# convert to data.table, by reference
setDT(dat)

dat[order(-z, b)]                  ## data.table, base R like syntax
setorder(dat, -z, b)               ## data.table, using setorder()
                                   ## setorder() now also works with data.frames 

# R-session memory usage (BEFORE) = ~2GB (size of 'dat')
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# Package      function    Time (s)  Peak memory   Memory used
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# doBy          orderBy      409.7        6.7 GB        4.7 GB
# taRifx           sort      400.8        6.7 GB        4.7 GB
# plyr          arrange      318.8        5.6 GB        3.6 GB 
# base R          order      299.0        5.6 GB        3.6 GB
# dplyr         arrange       62.7        4.2 GB        2.2 GB
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# data.table      order        6.2        4.2 GB        2.2 GB
# data.table   setorder        4.5        2.4 GB        0.4 GB
# ------------------------------------------------------------
```

- `data.table`'s `DT[order(...)]` syntax was **~10x** faster than the fastest of other methods (`dplyr`), while consuming the same amount of memory as `dplyr`.
- `data.table`'s `setorder()` was **~14x** faster than the fastest of other methods (`dplyr`), while taking **just 0.4GB extra memory**. `dat` is now in the order we require (as it is updated by reference).

#### data.table features:

**Speed:**

- *data.table*'s ordering is extremely fast because it implements [radix ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).
- The syntax `DT[order(...)]` is optimised internally to use *data.table*'s fast ordering as well. You can keep using the familiar base R syntax but speed up the process (and use less memory).

**Memory:**

- Most of the times, we don't require the original *data.frame* or *data.table* after reordering. That is, we usually assign the result back to the same object, for example:

  ```
  DF <- DF[order(...)]
  ```

  The issue is that this requires at least twice (2x) the memory of the original object. To be *memory efficient*, *data.table* therefore also provides a function `setorder()`.

  `setorder()` reorders *data.tables* `by reference` (*in-place*), without making any additional copies. It only uses extra memory equal to the size of one column.

**Other features:**

1. It supports `integer`, `logical`, `numeric`, `character` and even `bit64::integer64` types.

   > Note that `factor`, `Date`, `POSIXct` etc.. classes are all `integer`/`numeric` types underneath with additional attributes and are therefore supported as well.
2. In base R, we can not use `-` on a character vector to sort by that column in decreasing order. Instead we have to use `-xtfrm(.)`.

   However, in *data.table*, we can just do, for example, `dat[order(-x)]` or `setorder(dat, -x)`.

Comment: Thanks for this very instructive answer about data.table. Though, I don't understand what is "peak memory" and how you calculated it. Could you explain please ? Thank you !

Comment: I used [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) -> allocations and reported the "All heap and allocation VM" size.

Comment: @Arun the Instruments link in your comment is dead. Care to post an update?

Comment: @MichaelChirico
Here is a link to information about Instruments made by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/index.html

Answer (score 89):

With [this (very helpful) function by Kevin Wright](https://web.archive.org/web/20131108055534/http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips%3adata-frames%3asort), posted in the tips section of the R wiki, this is easily achieved.

```
sort(dd,by = ~ -z + b)
#     b x y z
# 4 Low C 9 2
# 2 Med D 3 1
# 1  Hi A 8 1
# 3  Hi A 9 1
```

Answer (score 48):

Suppose you have a `data.frame` `A` and you want to sort it using column called `x` descending order. Call the sorted `data.frame` `newdata`

```
newdata <- A[order(-A$x),]
```

If you want ascending order then replace `"-"` with nothing. You can have something like

```
newdata <- A[order(-A$x, A$y, -A$z),]
```

where `x` and `z` are some columns in `data.frame` `A`. This means sort `data.frame` `A` by `x` descending, `y` ascending and `z` descending.

Answer (score 46):

or you can use package doBy

```
library(doBy)
dd <- orderBy(~-z+b, data=dd)
```

Answer (score 45):

if SQL comes naturally to you, `sqldf` package handles `ORDER BY` as Codd intended.

Comment: MJM, thanks for pointing out this package. It's incredibly flexible and because half of my work is already done by pulling from sql databases it's easier than learning much of R's less than intuitive syntax.

Answer (score 38):

Alternatively, using the package Deducer

```
library(Deducer)
dd<- sortData(dd,c("z","b"),increasing= c(FALSE,TRUE))
```

Answer (score 28):

In response to a comment added in the OP for how to sort programmatically:

Using `dplyr` and `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
```

## dplyr

Just use `arrange_`, which is the Standard Evaluation version for `arrange`.

```
df1 <- tbl_df(iris)
#using strings or formula
arrange_(df1, c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width'))
arrange_(df1, ~Petal.Length, ~Petal.Width)
    Source: local data frame [150 x 5]

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          (dbl)       (dbl)        (dbl)       (dbl)  (fctr)
1           4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa
2           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
3           5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
4           5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2  setosa
5           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
6           5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4  setosa
7           5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2  setosa
8           4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
9           5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3  setosa
10          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
..          ...         ...          ...         ...     ...


#Or using a variable
sortBy <- c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width')
arrange_(df1, .dots = sortBy)
    Source: local data frame [150 x 5]

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          (dbl)       (dbl)        (dbl)       (dbl)  (fctr)
1           4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa
2           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
3           5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
4           5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2  setosa
5           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
6           5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2  setosa
7           4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
8           4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
9           5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3  setosa
10          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
..          ...         ...          ...         ...     ...

#Doing the same operation except sorting Petal.Length in descending order
sortByDesc <- c('desc(Petal.Length)', 'Petal.Width')
arrange_(df1, .dots = sortByDesc)
```

more info here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html

It is better to use formula as it also captures the environment to evaluate an expression in

## data.table

```
dt1 <- data.table(iris) #not really required, as you can work directly on your data.frame
sortBy <- c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width')
sortType <- c(-1, 1)
setorderv(dt1, sortBy, sortType)
dt1
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
  1:          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
  2:          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
  3:          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
  4:          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
  5:          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
 ---                                                            
146:          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4    setosa
147:          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2    setosa
148:          5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2    setosa
149:          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1    setosa
150:          4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2    setosa
```

Answer (score 28):

The arrange() in dplyr is my favorite option. Use the pipe operator and go from least important to most important aspect

```
dd1 <- dd %>%
    arrange(z) %>%
    arrange(desc(x))
```

Answer (score 26):

I learned about `order` with the following example which then confused me for a long time:

```
set.seed(1234)

ID        = 1:10
Age       = round(rnorm(10, 50, 1))
diag      = c("Depression", "Bipolar")
Diagnosis = sample(diag, 10, replace=TRUE)

data = data.frame(ID, Age, Diagnosis)

databyAge = data[order(Age),]
databyAge
```

The only reason this example works is because `order` is sorting by the `vector Age`, not by the column named `Age` in the `data frame data`.

To see this create an identical data frame using `read.table` with slightly different column names and without making use of any of the above vectors:

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '

  id age  diagnosis
   1  49 Depression
   2  50 Depression
   3  51 Depression
   4  48 Depression
   5  50 Depression
   6  51    Bipolar
   7  49    Bipolar
   8  49    Bipolar
   9  49    Bipolar
  10  49 Depression

', header = TRUE)
```

The above line structure for `order` no longer works because there is no vector named `age`:

```
databyage = my.data[order(age),]
```

The following line works because `order` sorts on the column `age` in `my.data`.

```
databyage = my.data[order(my.data$age),]
```

I thought this was worth posting given how confused I was by this example for so long.  If this post is not deemed appropriate for the thread I can remove it.

**EDIT: May 13, 2014**

Below is a generalized way of sorting a data frame by every column without specifying column names.  The code below shows how to sort from left to right or by right to left.  This works if every column is numeric.  I have not tried with a character column added.

I found the `do.call` code a month or two ago in an old post on a different site, but only after extensive and difficult searching.  I am not sure I could relocate that post now.  The present thread is the first hit for ordering a `data.frame` in `R`.  So, I thought my expanded version of that original `do.call` code might be useful.

```
set.seed(1234)

v1  <- c(0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1)
v2  <- c(0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1)
v3  <- c(0,0,1,1, 0,0,1,1, 0,0,1,1, 0,0,1,1)
v4  <- c(0,1,0,1, 0,1,0,1, 0,1,0,1, 0,1,0,1)

df.1 <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3, v4) 
df.1

rdf.1 <- df.1[sample(nrow(df.1), nrow(df.1), replace = FALSE),]
rdf.1

order.rdf.1 <- rdf.1[do.call(order, as.list(rdf.1)),]
order.rdf.1

order.rdf.2 <- rdf.1[do.call(order, rev(as.list(rdf.1))),]
order.rdf.2

rdf.3 <- data.frame(rdf.1$v2, rdf.1$v4, rdf.1$v3, rdf.1$v1) 
rdf.3

order.rdf.3 <- rdf.1[do.call(order, as.list(rdf.3)),]
order.rdf.3
```

Comment: That syntax does work if you store your data in a data.table, instead of a data.frame: `require(data.table); my.dt <- data.table(my.data); my.dt[order(age)]` This works because the column names are made available inside the [] brackets.

Comment: I don't think the downvote is necessary here, but neither do I think this adds much to the *question* at hand, particularly considering the existing set of answers, some of which already capture the requirement with `data.frame`s to either use `with` or `$`.

Comment: upvote for `do.call` this makes short work of sorting a multicolumn data frame. Simply `do.call(sort, mydf.obj)` and a beautiful cascade sort will be had.

Answer (score 23):

Dirk's answer is good but if you need the sort to persist you'll want to apply the sort back onto the name of that data frame.  Using the example code:

```
dd <- dd[with(dd, order(-z, b)), ]
```

Answer (score 12):

Just for the sake of completeness, since not much has been said about sorting by column numbers... It can surely be argued that it is often not desirable (because the order of the columns could change, paving the way to errors), but in some specific situations (when for instance you need a quick job done and there is no such risk of columns changing orders), it might be the most sensible thing to do, especially when dealing with large numbers of columns.

In that case, `do.call()` comes to the rescue:

```
ind <- do.call(what = "order", args = iris[,c(5,1,2,3)])
iris[ind, ]

##        Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
##    14           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa
##    9            4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa
##    39           4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2     setosa
##    43           4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
##    42           4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3     setosa
##    4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
##    48           4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2     setosa
##    7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa
##    (...)
```

Answer (score 9):

For the sake of completeness: you can also use the `sortByCol()` function from the `BBmisc` package:

```
library(BBmisc)
sortByCol(dd, c("z", "b"), asc = c(FALSE, TRUE))
    b x y z
4 Low C 9 2
2 Med D 3 1
1  Hi A 8 1
3  Hi A 9 1
```

Performance comparison:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(sortByCol(dd, c("z", "b"), asc = c(FALSE, TRUE)), times = 100000)
median 202.878

library(plyr)
microbenchmark(arrange(dd,desc(z),b),times=100000)
median 148.758

microbenchmark(dd[with(dd, order(-z, b)), ], times = 100000)
median 115.872
```

Comment: strange to add a performance comparison when your method is the slowest... anyway dubious the value of using a benchmark on a 4-row `data.frame`

Answer (score 7):

Just like the mechanical card sorters of long ago, first sort by the least significant key, then the next most significant, etc.  No library required, works with any number of keys and any combination of ascending and descending keys.

```
 dd <- dd[order(dd$b, decreasing = FALSE),]
```

Now we're ready to do the most significant key.  The sort is stable, and any ties in the most significant key have already been resolved.

```
dd <- dd[order(dd$z, decreasing = TRUE),]
```

This may not be the fastest, but it is certainly simple and reliable

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative, using the `rgr` package:

```
> library(rgr)
> gx.sort.df(dd, ~ -z+b)
    b x y z
4 Low C 9 2
2 Med D 3 1
1  Hi A 8 1
3  Hi A 9 1
```

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling with the above solutions when I wanted to automate my ordering process for n columns, whose column names could be different each time. I found a super helpful function from the `psych` package to do this in a straightforward manner:

```
dfOrder(myDf, columnIndices)
```

where `columnIndices` are indices of one or more columns, in the order in which you want to sort them. More information here:

[dfOrder function from 'psych' package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/1.8.4/topics/dfOrder)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, `{collapse}` offers a rapidly fast function named `roworder`, which also handles quite a few optional arguments.

```r
> collapse::roworder(dd, -z, b)
    b x y z
1 Low C 9 2
2 Med D 3 1
3  Hi A 8 1
4  Hi A 9 1
```

Be aware of

> **Description**
> A fast substitute for dplyr::arrange. It returns a sorted copy of the data frame, unless the data is already sorted in which case no copy is made. In addition, rows can be manually re-ordered. Use data.table::setorder to sort a data frame without creating a copy.

from the help file (`?roworder`).